# What is the best way to insert characters into specific string positions based on delimiter

Tags: delphi

I have a csv file that has values like these:

```
3421, Mar wen, 3.4, Nano
2312, Klen, 2.1, LR
```

Separating the values above with comma, I need to surround values at 1,2,4 positions with single quote character. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Use a parameterized query and let the library do the work for you.

Comment: Stop using concatenated SQL and use parameters instead. You won't have to worry about adding quotes, formatting dates, or SQL injection.

Comment: please give me any simple example

Comment: This is not a give me the code website, you must know that by now. Just use the search function on SO and enter "delphi sql parameter".

Comment: If I used parameters query then I must split the string line of the csv file ?

Comment: @J I added the info, I know how to extract data I just want to know if I should split each value and feed it into the query ?

Comment: yes you need to split the values and feed them individually to each parameter in the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi has a very useful SplitString function that can help you. It puts every element in a string array, so you can very easily access to the first, second and fourth element and do whatever you need with them (like setting your query parameters).

```
uses System.StrUtils, System.Types
...
...
var Values: TStringDynArray;
begin
  Values := SplitString('3421, Mar wen, 3.4, Nano', ', ');
  ShowMessage('First Value: ' + Values[0]);
  ShowMessage('Second Value: ' + Values[1]);
  ShowMessage('Fourth Value: ' + Values[3]);
end;
```